# App Engine Updating service default Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app to Google App Engine. When I run the command `gcloud app deploy`, it finish all the task, but then it get stack on the "update service".
At first I got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

Then I increase the timeout time, but I still got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation [apps/artise-server/operations/a3a9a2ac-f33b-4c94-93f1-88917372703e] timed out. This operation may still be underway.
```

This is my .yaml config:

```
runtime: python
runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.6
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
liveness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 60
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 1
  initial_delay_sec: 3600

readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: 300
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 10
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1800

endpoints_api_service:
  name: artise-server.appspot.com
  rollout_strategy: managed
```

If I go to "Build Cloud" section, all the build have the green check, so they succeed.

If I check the log, the only error I see is about memory:

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /root/.cache/pip/http/0/6/0/1/c/0601ce0a759e906a3c59f237e6f51f593631e6614dfdd40374a20b3e: no space left on device
```

If i go to the url of the project, the 404 not found page by Google is shown.
And the post request don't return the response. So I think my server is not online.

Answer (score 1):

The First Error `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.` can be due to different things:

- Not having enough  resources
- Not having permissions in the VPC Network in case you have special VPC configurations.

For the first possibility increasing resources on the app.yaml can be enough.

> ```
> resources:
>  cpu: 2
>  memory_gb: 2.3
>  disk_size_gb: 10
>  volumes:
>  - name: ramdisk1
>    volume_type: tmpfs
>    size_gb: 0.5
> ```

For the Second Error: `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation [apps/artise-server/operations/a3a9a2ac-f33b-4c94-93f1-88917372703e] timed out. This operation may still be underway.`

This can be due deploying again with the same version ID, please try to deploy again with a different version ID, to set the version ID when deploying you can do it by deploying with the following line:

```
gcloud app deploy --version=VERSION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that there might be insufficient resources. Try increasing default values for mermory as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings).
Example:

> ```
> resources:
>   cpu: 2
>   memory_gb: 2.3
>   disk_size_gb: 10
>   volumes:
>   - name: ramdisk1
>     volume_type: tmpfs
>     size_gb: 0.5
> ```

Comment: Still got the second error I post above

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance deploying with a Virtual Private Cloud? If so, the first error message you are getting suggests the issue might be related to the VPC’s firewall. Can you verify your firewall rules?

Comment: Where should I check If I'm using a Virtual Private Cloud? Inside the section "AppEngine" --> "Firewall Rules" is all "accept"

Comment: Your app might be consuming too many resources and never arriving at a ready state because it's taking too long to load. Try further increasing CPU, disk space and wait time again. Do you get the same error message if you deploy your app on your local machine?